# Have multiple versions of Nginx on Debian

Tags: debian, make, nginx

I have a standard version of Nginx (installed through `apt-get`) running my production environment (Debian Jessie).

Now I want to compile the most recent release of Nginx from source with some extra modules for testing. The executable may sit anywhere, but I want to make sure not to accidentally overwrite my production version.

**What I know:** I need to `cd` to nginx source directory and execute:

```
./configure --add-module=/path/to/some/module
make
make install
```

**What I don't know:** How to make sure that the test version doesn't install on top of the production version. Or how to install in a specific place I specify.

(I tried to read the man-pages on make but didn't come to any conclusive answer. I am rather inexperiences with compiling from source.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify the installation target as an option to `./configure`, not `make`. By default, nginx configures itself with a prefix of `/usr/local/nginx`, so there's no risk of overwriting the packaged version; you can specify your own path with

```
./configure --prefix=/your/installation/path
```

The default nginx setup doesn't install any files outside of its prefix, *e.g.* in `/etc`.

The installation process is documented on [the nginx web site](https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html).

A general strategy to check whether a piece of software is safe to install from source is to run the *installation* step with the `-n` option (which tells Make not to actually do anything):

```
make -n install
```

This will list all the operations that *would* be done in a real installation. (Some build systems break with this option because later installation steps rely on the changes made by earlier ones; nginx's build works fine.)

Of course you should play around with the source build and installation steps on another system first, before touching your production system...

Comment: thank's a lot. I was reading about it but wasn't sure on that point, especially if ```/etc``` files would be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `./configure` with the `--sbin-path=` option:

> [--sbin-path=path](https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) — sets the name of an nginx executable file. This name is used only during installation. By default the file is named `prefix/sbin/nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to do the configuration. Afterwards you can create new virtual machines (e.g. with [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)) and rollout your ansible-configuration (so called *playbooks*).